# Queries working in snowflake web UI but not consistently through the python sqlalchemy connector

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sqlalchemy connection setup to snowflake which works, as I can run some queries and get results out. The attempts to query are also logged in my user_query history.

My connection:

```
engine = create_engine(URL(
  user, password, account, database, warehouse, role
))

connection = engine.connect()
```

However, most of the time my queries fail returning Operational Error (i.e. its a snowflake error) https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#error-e3q8. But these same queries will run fine in the snowflake web UI.

For example if I run

```
test_query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1'
test = pd.read_sql(test_query, connection)
```

When I look at my query_history it shows the sqlalchemy query failing, then a second later the base query itself being run successfully. However I'm not sure where this output goes in the snowflake setup, and why its not transferring through my sqlalchemy connection.  What I'm seeing...

- Query = 'DESC TABLE /* sqlalchemy:_has_object */ "SELECT * FROM DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1"

  Error code = 2003 Error message = SQL compilation error: Database
  '"SELECT * FROM DB1" does not exist.

Then 1 second later, the query itself will run successfully, but not clear where this goes as it doesn't get sent over the connection.

- Query = SELECT * FROM TABLE DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you try using only "test_query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1'" since you have already mentioned the database and schema in the connection?

Comment: I gave that a try and still facing the same problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding schema also here

```
engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = '',
    user = '',
    password = '',
    database = '',
    schema = '',
    warehouse = '',
    role='',
))

connection = engine.connect()
```

Comment: The parameters account etc have string values, I just haven't added them here for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that the query is running in WebUI and fails with syntax error when connected via CLI or other modes.

Suggest you print the query which is via CLI or via a connector, run the same to WebUI and also note that from which role you're running the query.

Please share what is your finding.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  If I use the code `SELECT * FROM TABLE DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1` in the WebUI it works. Then when I run it through the SqlAlchemy connector it fails, but in the query_history of my user it is showing that the SqlAlchemy attempt didn't work, but then theres a  ROLLBACK and then it ran the query 'as-is' a second later, which was successful.  Is there some syntax I'm missing around the query above for SqlAlchmey snowflake to read it properly, or some way to extract this successful attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned query (SELECT * FROM TABLE DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1) is not a snowflake supported SQL syntax.

Link [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs.html#query-syntax) will help you more with details.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your failed DESC TABLE queries are likely due to a pandas implementation issue as described here.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Thousands-of-Failed-SQL-Queries-from-SQL-Alchemy-sqlalchemy-has-object

The numerous rollbacks are probably due to your connection pool behavior, which is likely set to reset on return, i.e. when a connection is returned to the pool, it executes a rollback (essentially a no-op) in order to clear the transactional state.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35390856)